# How do I get url parameters with nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I've written an application that, on apache, has no issue getting the parameters of `url.com/home/index/test` and returning `/home/index/test` when I echo in php.  On nginx when I go to `url.com/?something=test` it returns `test`

However, when I put the same app on nginx it just returns a blank white page. The network tab says `200` so its not returning any errors for me. This is my nginx block.  I don't think this is code related.  I think its server side.

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/c/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name server_domain_or_IP;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

EDIT: adding php code

This is my app file that processes the urls

```
<?php

class App
{
protected $controller = 'home';
protected $method     = 'index';
protected $params     = [];

public function __construct()
{
   return print_r($this->parseUrl());
}

public function parseUrl()
{
    if(isset($_GET['url']))
    {
        return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
}
```

}

This is the controller

```
<?php
class Home extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'home/index';
    }
}
```

You can see the full repo here https://github.com/CircleFramework/Circle/tree/0.1-dev

This is my fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;
fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
```

Comment: Can you please add your php code and the nginx fastcgi_params file content ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on my site after an update of nginx.
Replace

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

with

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Something on fastcgi_split_path_info triggered this error.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. It created a 502 bad gateway

Comment: Sorry when it don't work for you. After updating my nginx server i got the problem you descript, and this was the solution.